# How does StringBuffer synchronization work?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, stringbuffer

Greetings to everyone!

I'm a bit confused as to in what way/under what circumstances StringBuffer is synchronized and prevents multi-threaded access. In the code below it prints out the letters in the for loop A 100 times then B 100 times etc... comment out the synchronized (sb){} part and it is no longer synch'd and doesn't work....

How then is the StringBuffer synchronized... under what restrictions will it work ?  Could someone explain in simple terms ? Does it have to be atomic operations ?

Thanks !

John.

```
package threads.sync.ch13;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Ex13_2 extends Thread {

static StringBuffer sb;
// StringBuilder sb;
String s;

public Ex13_2(StringBuffer sb) {

    this.sb = sb;

}

public void run() {
    synchronized (sb) {
        // incr letter then print 100 X
        sb.replace(0, sb.length(), this.s);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.print(this.sb);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    // single Class Buffer per Instance...
    sb = new StringBuffer("");

    // Create Array of Multiple Thread Instances
    // and start running them...
    List<Ex13_2> e = new ArrayList<>();

    for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'D'; c++) {
        Ex13_2 t = new Ex13_2(sb);
        t.s = c + "";
        e.add(t);

    }

    for (Ex13_2 t : e) {
        t.start();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: BrianT.'s answer touches on a very important point.  StringBuilder is considered to be "thread safe" because, no matter how many threads attempt access the same instance at the same time, and no matter what they do to it, they can not put the instance into a bad state.  But that does _not_ always mean that appends will happen in the order that you wanted them to happen:  You might need additional synchronization for that because... Building a program entirely out of "thread-safe" objects does not make the _program_ thread safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each method in `StringBuilder` **is** thread safe. But you are calling various methods in sequence. So each call to a method is mutually exclusive, but not the whole series of calls.

By putting the whole series into a `synchronized(sb) {}` block, you make the whole series of calls mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 3):

First off, for non-shared use StringBuilder is superior (it was written for this purpose... it is completely unsynchronized and so a bit faster).

Back to StringBuffer.  All of its public methods are synchronized, so it is internally "safe".  But the following is not atomic:

```
StringBuffer sb = //get_sb_from_somewhere;
sb.append("foo").append("bar);
```

To make the appends completely thread safe, wrap them in a lock, using the same lock the object would use.  Usually this is simply the object, as is the case here, so:

```
synchronized (sb) {
  sb.append("foo").append("bar);
}
```

Your run() method looks good to me.